# Prepositions for the word "Zeit"

Tags: preposition

I have encountered many times two prepositions for "Zeit", in and zu.

> in dieser Zeit
>
> zu dieser Zeit

It may sound mundane to natural speakers but I'm just curious, is there any difference between them?

Comment: It's like in English: *during this time (span)* versus *at this (point of) time*.

Comment: Da wo nur drei mit der Idee übereinstimmen, dass diese Frage anhand eines WB zu lösen wäre, würde ich vorschlagen zumindest einen besseren Tittel zu wählen (die Frage geht nur um zwei Präp.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, in different contexts:

1. In dieser Zeit war ich schwanger.
2. Zu dieser Zeit war ich schwanger.

In both cases you refer to a time - while the first option refers to a time span, the second option will *mostly* refer to a point of time :

1. During this time I was pregnant.
2. At this time I was pregnant

I've chosen this example to point out that `zu dieser Zeit` can also refer to a time span - in case the reference `dieser Zeit` is a time span too.

Comment: Thanks a lot!!!